# Exclude dir from a Security-Contraint

Tags: security, tomcat, filter, tomcat7

I'm trying to redirect all the trafic under a directory (tomcat Webapps directory) to https, all but excluding one application. The problem is that my tomcat 7 filters all traffic under / with https, but the previous exception is ignored...

Here an example into my /tomcat7/conf/web.xml

```
> <security-constraint>
>     <web-resource-collection>
>         <web-resource-name>app1</web-resource-name>
>         <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
>      </web-resource-collection> 
>  </security-constraint>
> 
>  <security-constraint>
>      <web-resource-collection>
>         <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
>          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>      </web-resource-collection>
>     <user-data-constraint>
>         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> </user-data-constraint> 
>  </security-constraint>
```

How can i add a exception to go with http and all the other traffic with https???

Comment: Why did you modify `conf/web.xml`? That's the system-wide default configuration for all deployed applications. I think you probably want to configure each application individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>` where you don't want https, telling tomcat to ignore that specific pages.

Comment: i've tried but don't work, i've tried too `<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>app1</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/cd_webservice_preview/*</url-pattern>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>`
But don't work too